# Using Where-Object for accessing folders with administrator permission

Tags: powershell

I would like to scan windows folder to find files that are created in a specific data range and export it to a csv file. Although I have opened a powershell as administrator, I still see some "access denied" messages.

```
PS C:\Windows> Get-ChildItem . -recurse  | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge "07/01/2021" -and $_.CreationTime -le "07/31/2021" } | Export-Csv 'e:\scans.csv'
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied.
...
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Doubt this will change much but, try `-Force`. Other than that, check the permissions on that folder vs the one on your account

Comment: If you run as administrator `Get-Acl C:\Windows\CSC` you receive `CSC  AUTORITE NT\Système AUTORITE NT\Système Allow  FullControl` it means that you can't get the containt of this folder as simple administrator.

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Get-ChildItem` call to ignore the errors.

Answer (score 1):

A known trick is to install the [sysInternals suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) to use `psexec.exe` and to run your script in a powershell as System:

```
psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe
```

Then at least `C:\windows\CSC` is available.

Comment: It solves some of the problems, but I see `'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5' is denied.`